# For each loop in MVC Razor Views is slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

So I have a razor view and I give it about 1000 records.
I have a foreach loop around those records and they just display a table row per record.

Side Note: I can achieve the same with React really fast, but I want to use MVC Razor Views.

```
<table>
@foreach (var b in @Model) {
   @<tr>
     ....
    </tr>

}
</table>
```

The rendering of this takes about 20-30 seconds, what am I doing wrong and what am I missing?
Getting the data from the database takes like half a second.  So the slowness isn't in the DB part.

Comment: Can you post the result of typeof(@Model)?

Comment: The 20 to 30 seconds you mentioned, was this recorded during debugging / development machine or after deployment?

Comment: What exactly are you doing in the `foreach`? Are you simply just displaying data or are you going off to a database?

Comment: If you just access once to var b in each loop, you should use a for instead of foreach, would make it slightly faster.

Comment: The model is fairly large, but in essence it is just a bunch of string fields being displayed. The data and all logic has already been done and is all ready to go when it comes to the razor view. Inside the forloop I'm checking an if and then displaying data, no database connection.  This is happening on debug and on prod.

Comment: Are you using some lazy loading in this Model?

Comment: No lazy loading. The model is full and ready to be displayed. Just a List of items.

Comment: I think we need a [mcve] in order to help you.  `foreach` is not inherently slow, it's something else you're doing.

Comment: *The rendering of this takes about 20-30 seconds* Please describe exactly how you are measuring this. Are you using a stopwatch while watching the page appear on your browser? Or are you looking at gaps in timestamps in server logs? Etc. Depending on how you're measuring it, the issue could simply be your wifi.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, but I found the answer.  It wasn't the `forloop` it was that I had a `JSON.Stringify` on the page.  Duh!!